# Create python string with fill char and counter

Tags: python, string

I'd like to do it in an elegant fashion:

```
>>> ''.zfill(5, '-')
'-----'
```

There's any way to initialize a string with a fill char and a counter?
Of course, count may vary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just try:

```
>>> '-'*5
'-----'
```

It's that simple in Python :)

Comment: That is really great! It would never pass on my mind it could be done this way.

Answer (score 1):

The [introduction to strings in the "official" tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) says:

> Strings can be concatenated (glued
>   together) with the `+` operator, and
>   repeated with `*`

Comment: A little odd for someone coming from C ;)